# Why was my question on WAMPSERVER closed?

Tags: discussion

I usually understand why people close questions on StackOverflow but in this case, since there was no comments, I really do not understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185340/why-do-i-get-a-wamp-homepage-when-clicking-on-specific-websites-url-on-localhos I hope you can help me understand what I have done wrong and how I can correct it.

Comment: I have transfered the question to server fault http://serverfault.com/questions/484230/pages-of-website-returns-a-wamp-homepage-on-my-localhost

Comment: After getting even more replies, I have transfered it to superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/560162/pages-of-website-returns-a-wamp-homepage-on-my-localhost

Answer (score 2):

You've provided a very superficial description, no server logs, no error messages, no configuration settings. You don't mention the exact steps you followed in your setup. There is not nearly enough information to answer the question in a manner that meets StackOverflow's quality standards.

Comment: Thanks, I have added more information on the exact step, there are no error messages in this case. What can i provide in this case as configuration settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is no programming querstion. It is a configuration question and should IMO be closed as *off-topic* instead of *not a real question*.

And the little info you provided made it really hard to help you. That would justify the *not a real question* close reason because that is all very vage.

Comment: Hi juergen, should I transfer the question to superuser? I have added some details, anything else I could add?

Comment: I just saw the question was migrated. I am no expert on WAMP. Sit tight for comments asking for clarification.

Comment: juergen, thanks, do you know if superuser is best for wamp question?

Comment: WAMP questions should generally be on-topic for SO, provided they concern someone's development or testing environment.